# Autentificación HTTP

Tags: javascript, nodejs, autenticación

Trabajo en **NodeJs**, en mi aplicación, tengo un comando que manda un request de la siguiente manera:

```
var request = require('request')
let input = params.join('+').toLowerCase();
const baseUrl = 'https://myanimelist.net/api/anime/search.xml?q=';
const theUrl = baseUrl + input;
request({
      url: theUrl,
      json: false,
  }, (error, response, body) => {
});
```

Sin embargo, al hacer una búsqueda, éste requiere una autentificación, que fácilmente puedo hacerlo desde el navegador (ya que éste almacena cookies) y puedo insertar de manera manual, pero no sé cómo autentificarme de manera automática a través de mi aplicación (uso **NodeJs v7.4.0**).

[image: Autentificación]

La documentación de esta API está [aquí](https://myanimelist.net/modules.php?go=api).

EDIT: Cambié el paquete que hace el request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La autentificación ha funcionado correctamente con el siguiente código.

```
var request = require('request')
    username = "username",
    password = "password",
    auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");

let input = params.join('+').toLowerCase();
const baseUrl = 'https://myanimelist.net/api/anime/search.xml?q=';
const theUrl = baseUrl + input;
console.log(theUrl);
request({
    url: theUrl,
    headers : {
          "Authorization" : auth
    }
}, (error, response, body) => {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
});
```